# absolute positioned image content on list before pseudo element in IE (11)

Tags: css, css-position, internet-explorer-11, absolute

I'm trying to set an image on a :before pseudo element.
It works on all browsers except IE11 of course.
Here the positioning doesn't work as expected.

```
<ol>
    <li>
        :before

li {
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    content: url('image.svg');
    position: absolute;
    width: 2.3em
    top: 2.5em;
    left: 1.2em;
}
```

The problem is that IE11 seems to have problems with the image content. It works with text but not with the `content: url()`.

This is what text looks like with `top: 0; left: 0;`:
[image]

And this what the image looks like with `top: 0; left: 0;`:
[image]

Is there some special thing needed for IE11 to make this work. Or is it just not possible to do it in this way?
How would you position these elements so they work in most browsers and IE11?

Comment: Have you tried adding the SVG as a `background-image`, rather than in the `content` property?

Comment: I think there was a reason I didn't do that. But I can't remember. I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yep it seems that works. And I can't remember why I used the content.

Comment: If you could add it as answer I can check it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `content`, try using `background-image` property and adjust position as you need...

```css
li:before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('image.svg');
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 2.3em;
    height: //
    background-size: //
    top: 2.5em;
    left: 1.2em;
}
```